# Not equal xPath query limitations

Tags: xpath, event-viewer

I need to find logs from EventViewer in Forwarded Events based on computer name, excluding the ones which aren't interesting for me.

My query is like that

```
*[(System[(Computer!='comp1')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp2')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp3')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp4')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp5')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp6')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp7')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp8')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp9')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp10')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp11')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp12')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp13')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp14')]) and 
(System[(Computer!='comp15')])]
```

This query works fine unless I add one more condition

```
and [(Computer!='comp16')])
```

After that filter stops working and all logs are displayed.
Notice that if I put `comp16` instead of `comp15` or instead of `comp12` everything works fine. So problem is not in the new condition.

The situation is opposite if I use equality filter

```
(System[(Computer='comp1')]) or 
(System[(Computer='comp2')]) or
...
(System[(Computer='comp15')]) or 
(System[(Computer='comp16')]) and so on
```

Filter works fine with much larger queries.

So why not equal operator does not work in large queries?

**EDIT**

Filter by EventRecordID has the same problem

**EDIT 2**

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
  <EventID>4624</EventID> 
  <Version>1</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12544</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-08-18T17:06:15.595105400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="584" ThreadID="7100" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>comp1</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
 </System>
<EventData>
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">userName</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetDomainName">DOMAIN</Data> 
  ...
  <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">-</Data> 
 </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: XPath queries should work fine with more than 15 `!=` conditions... Share log which you're trying to parse and tool you use. If you need workaround, try `[System[not(Computer='comp1') and not(Computer='comp2') and ...]]` or `[System[not(Computer=('comp1', 'comp2', ...)]]`

Comment: @Andersson I use standart EventViewer tool "Filter Current Log", tab "XML". Also I try to do it programmatically in `C#` using `EventLogWatcher` and `EventLogQuery` classes. The results are the same

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your XML, but it's hard to envisage an XML structure on which this query makes any sense.

Consider the simpler

```
*[(System[(Computer!='comp1')]) and 
  (System[(Computer!='comp2')])]
```

If there is only one System with only one Computer, then this returns true if the Computer is neither 'comp1' nor 'comp2'. But if there is more than one System, or more than one Computer, and if the Computers are not all the same value, then there will inevitably be at least one Computer that is not 'comp1', and at least one that is not 'comp2', and the predicate will therefore always be true.

Usually when people write `A!=B` in XPath, they should have written `not(A=B)`.

Comment: My XML is standart Windows Event Log (see EDIT 2)

Your answer doesn't explain why my query works fine with 15 conditions but doesn't work with 16 and more when filter exactly the same batch of logs.

By the way, EventViewer Logs filter doesn't have operator `not()`, only `!=`, or maybe I just don't know the right way to use it

Comment: Since your XML elements are in a namespace I don't see how any of these XPath queries can work at all. Ah: I see that at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer/ it says "Windows Event Log supports a subset of XPath 1.0. " So this isn't really a question about XPath at all, it's about some peculiar variant of it.

Comment: Found information on the XPath dialect here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996910(VS.85).aspx#limitations I wonder why they went to all the effort of producing a non-conformant custom XPath implementation just for this job?

Comment: Yeah, I`ve seen these articles and few others and found nothing about any query length restrictions as far as conditions count restrictions. With regard to their own implementation of xPath I think the reasons were the same as the reasons to implement their own jQuery (called mQuery) for Sharepoint :)

Comment: By the way, why you told that since XML elements are in a namespace they shouldn't work at all?

Comment: In standard path an unprefixed name will only match an element in no namespace.

Comment: (Sorry: "path" in that comment was the spell-corrector on my phone mangling "XPath")